# Java - Dice Game, Player starts with 100 points, subtract 10 for each roll

Tags: java

I am making a dice game where there are two players, and each player starts with 100 points. For each roll, the player loses 10 points, but based off the sum they get from the two dice, they will gain some points. My error is that the loop does not stop (it keeps looping). Here is the code:

```
public class DiceGameC {

    private static Die die = new Die(12);
    private static Player p1 = new Player("Wasi");
    private static Player p2 = new Player("Pruthvi");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        do {
            p1.rollDie(die);
            setPlayerScore(p1);
            p2.rollDie(die);
            setPlayerScore(p2);
        }
        while (p1.getScore() != 0 || p2.getScore() != 0);

        if(p1.getScore() == 0) {
            System.out.println(p1.getName() + " lost the game! The winner is: " + p2.getName());
        }
        else if(p2.getScore() == 0) {
            System.out.println(p2.getName() + " lost the game! The winner is: " + p1.getName());
        }
    }

    private static void setPlayerScore(Player player) {

        int playerScore = player.getScore();

        if(player.getDiceValue(die) == 2) {
            player.setScore(playerScore);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 3) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 2);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 4) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 3);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 5) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 5);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 6) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 7);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 7) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 10);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 8) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 11);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 9) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 13);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 10) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 15);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 11) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 17);
        }
        else if (player.getDiceValue(die) == 12) {
            player.setScore(playerScore + 20);
        }

    }

}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private int score;
    private Die die;

    public Player() {
        this.setName("Anonymous");
        this.setScore(100);
    }

    public Player(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public void rollDie(Die die) {
        die.rollDie();
        setScore(score - 10);
    }

    public int getDiceValue(Die die) {
        return die.getValue();
    }

}
```

Die Class:

```
public class Die {

    // Instance variables (properties / attributes / data)

    private int faces;
    private int value;

    /*
     * Creates an instance of Die
     */

    public Die() {
        // regular die
        this.faces = 6;

    }

    public Die(int faces) {
        this.faces = faces;
    }

    // behaviour for a Die - a method roll my die
    public void rollDie() {
        this.value = (int)(Math.random() * this.faces + 1);
    }

    // getter method for getting the value
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create two Dice objects
        Die d1 = new Die();
        Die d2 = new Die();

        d1.rollDie(); // roll the first die
        d2.rollDie(); //roll the second die

        System.out.println(d1.getValue());
        System.out.println(d2.getValue());

        Die d3 = new Die(20); // create a value with 20 faces

        d3.rollDie();
        System.out.println(d3.getValue());
    }

    public boolean equals(Die die) {
        return this.value == die.getValue();
    }

    public boolean equalsOtherWay(Die die) {
        if(this.value == die.getValue()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What loop? Please explain the details of your problem.

Comment: This `for(int i = 0; i < )` doesn't  even compile

Comment: that for loop is not complete. Looks like a typo! Sorry if I am explaining trivial things, but a for loop need a stop condition, and the increment step; `for(int i = 0; i < something; i++ )`

Comment: Please ignore the for loop part, my mistake was not taking it out. I meant the do while loop.

Comment: Other than what Andew answered, you're not setting the score to 100 when creating a new Player with a name. Java will instantiate the score field for you, but it'll be 0.

Comment: Is there any rule how the dice values affect the score? You should really think about trying to make the huge `if-else` thing compact. It looks like its mainly `+2` and sometimes `+3`. You only need two `if` conditions then. Note that you can combine logical expressions by using *logical and* `&&` and *logical or* `||`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace the condition in the while loop. You say :

```
 while (p1.getScore() != 0 || p2.getScore() != 0);
```

But player's score may be < 0 , so player's score will never be 0.
So you have to change the condition so as for the loop to stop if the score becomes < 0, like that :

```
while (p1.getScore() > 0 && p2.getScore() > 0);
```

Comment: This makes sense. I completely forgot about the value going below zero.

Comment: We all make this mistakes sometimes, just try out ways that will help you find the mistake, like printing the score of each player in the loop, so  you can monitor how the score changes.